# set background-size with DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I wanted to set the `background-size` with the following code but it's not doing anything. I was expecting my image to be reduced by half but it's still 100% along both axis?

```
var BG_IMG_TAG = document.getElementById("body");       
    BG_IMG_TAG.setAttribute("style", "background-size: 50% 50%;");
```

here's my css sheet

```
body
{   
    background-image:url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat;       
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem here.  You're using `document.getElementById("body")` which is looking for an element with `id="body"` and then your CSS refers to `body` which is the `<body>` tag.  You need to decide which ONE you're using.  If you want both to be the `<body>` tag, then use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementById("body")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style` property , If you want to apply style for an element with `id` as `body` then use

```
var BG_IMG_TAG = document.getElementById("body");       
    BG_IMG_TAG.style = "background-size: 50% 50%";
```

If you want to apply style to `body` tag then you should use , since in your code you are using `getElementById()` wich will select item with `id` as `body` not the `body` tag

```
var BG_IMG_TAG = document.body;       
    BG_IMG_TAG.style = "background-size: 50% 50%";
```

or try with your own code

```
var BG_IMG_TAG = document.body;       
    BG_IMG_TAG.setAttribute("style", "background-size: 50% 50%;");
```

Comment: I guess, but when do I use `setAttribute` and then your solution for these style sheets?

Comment: `var BG_IMG_TAG = document.getElementById("body");    ` doesn't work it's `var BG_IMG_TAG = document.body;  ` that works.